# сообщество по автоматизации

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

День добрый. Хочу знать, есть ли что либо на Stack Owerflow по АСУ ТП и вообще по промышленной автоматике? И можно ли как то развить эту тематику, возможно с созданием отдельного сообщества по промышленной автоматике и управлению? Разделов довольно много - достаточно глянуть на любой форум производителя автоматики, а вот централизованного сообщества, где можно задать вопрос и получить ответ я так и не нашел, может плохо искал?)
З.Ы, например не нашел метки ST Codesys - популярный язык программирования контроллеров. По SCADA - тоже не находит меток, 7 вопросов и те, лишь косвенные, хотя существует множество вариантов, в том числе и бесплатных и условно-бесплатных. В общем автоматизированные системы в промышленности все более популярны, но я только месяц проработав в этой области столкнулся с массовой безграмотностью - одна разводка RS-485 звездой чего стоит)))

Comment: из существующих сообществ возможно могут подойти http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ и http://engineering.stackexchange.com/ ну и сам http://stackoverflow.com/. Это все на английском. Отдельного сообщества на русском - не будет. Поэтому в принципе по scada и Codesys можно задавать вопросы на ruSO. Проблема скорее будет в том, что может не найтись кому на них отвечать.

Comment: Странно, на английском есть, на русском нету))) Такое ощущение, словно в России нету автоматизации производства) А насчет некому отвечать... Ну может я хочу не только вопрошать но и оставлять замечания и свой опыт работы)

Comment: На самом деле ничего странного: тут уже были темы, почему не будет дополнительных сообществ на русском.